# zendframework and uploadify integration

Tags: zend-framework, uploadify

I have a small issue with integrating uploadify with zendframework. I have found a lot of posts about this issue but none of them able to help me.

in uploadify script when I use this

```
'script': '/uploadtest.php',
```

It works perfectly alright.

but when I use this and call a action in controller like this.

```
'script': 'http://zendbase.local/asset/asset/addedit',
```

OR

`'script': '/asset/asset/addedit'`,

It does not work.

while above url is accessible directly. but somehow swf uploadify is not calling this url successfully while it shows me bar with 100% success.

Any idea?

edit:
I have tried this solution mentioned at http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/1848/zend-framework-integration-help/p1

```
'script': '<?php echo $this->url(array('module' => 'asset', 'controller' => 'asset', 'action' => 'addedit')) ?>',
```

but gives me a error "Message: Cannot assemble. Reversed route is not specified."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out the solution. It was stupid mistake. my controller was not accessible for every one and it was returning the login page as response. so I change the rights in my ACL and it works fine. 
I recommend Charles Proxy (http://www.charlesproxy.com) for debugging which helped me a lot to read the response from swf call.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with the same error

> cannot assemble. reversed route is not specified

The solution, like they wrote in zend manual

"Since regex patterns are not easily reversed, you will need to prepare a reverse URL if you wish to use a URL helper or even an assemble method of this class. This reversed path is represented by a string parsable by sprintf() and is defined as a fourth construct parameter:"

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
    'archive/(\d+)',
    array( ... ),
    array('year' => 1),
    'archive/%s'
);
```

I found the solution in this thread

[Zend community thread](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Using-url-view-helper-with-regex-route-td660695.html)